The difference in user home directories access from live USB sticks
I created two users on my Mint 21.3 system:

user1 (1000) was created during installation
user2 (1001) I added later

Both have their home directories in /home, with exactly the same drwxr-x--- permissions. Neither is encrypted.
The problem is that none of the distros I tried as live USB sticks (Ubuntu and flavors, Mint, Fedora and spins) allow me to access /home/user2. Most but not all allow /home/user1. The only difference between the users is that user1 is an administrator and user2 is not.
My question: why does it happen?

The default user in many live systems has uid 1000 (the first “user” uid in most systems), so it is considered as the owner of /home/user1. /home/user2 is owned by uid 1001 and presumably gid 1001, which won’t match the live user; so the “other” permissions apply.

So, the reason why one of the live distros did not allow me access even to /home/user1 was probably that this particular distro's live user is not 1000?

That’s the most plausible reason, yes.
